# Average of every 3 rows

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a sheet like this:

```
    A    B
1   32   22 
2   25   44
3   10   58
4   14
5   87
6   32
7   5
8   97
9   73
```

The sheet in reality has hundreds of rows. I need a formula that averages the first 3 cells of column A, and then if I copy this formula to the next row it would average A4:A6, and then the next row would average A7:A9, and so forth. My desired result is shown in column B. Is such a thing possible? I've tried all kinds of variations using INDIRECT, ADDRESS, etc. But nothing so far has worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The starting row numbers are assumed to be 1, 4, 7, and so on. In general it is `3n-2`

The second row number is `3n-2+1`, and the third is `3n-2+2`

This is the formula:

`=(indirect(concat("A",(3*(row())-2))) + indirect(concat("A",(3*row())-2+1)) + indirect(concat("A",(3*row())-2+2))) / 3`

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image: E1]

If the starting row numbers are 2,5,8.. then the generalised form is `3n-1` for the first row, `3n` for the second, `3n+1` for the third. But again inputs from `row()` would start at 2. So, we would need to deduct `1`. Thus, `(3*(row()-1)-1` is `3(n-1)-1` and so on.

This is the formula:

`=(indirect(concat("A",(3*(row()-1)-1))) + indirect(concat("A",(3*(row()-1)))) + indirect(concat("A",(3*(row()-1)+1)))) / 3`

Example 2:

[image: E2]

Can be done in this way as well:

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCAT("A",(3*(ROW()-1)-1))):INDIRECT(CONCAT("A",(3*(ROW()-1)+1))))`

Final example:

[image: E3]

Answer (score 0):

Another, just for fun:

```
=ArrayFormula(ROUND(MMULT(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/3),3,2,1),{ROW(A:A),A:A},2,FALSE),SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/3),1,1,0))/3))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Contiguous Results

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IFERROR(
   1/(1/NOT(MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3)))*
   1/(1/(LEN(r)/LEN(r)))*
   AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0))))),1)
```

[image]

#### Non-Contiguous Results

To return the results in line with the current row being calculated (every 3rd row) simply remove the [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) function:

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IFERROR(
   1/(1/NOT(MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3)))*
   1/(1/(LEN(r)/LEN(r)))*
   AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0)))))
```

[image]

## Explanation

Below I refer to every third row starting from the row containing the formula as a **calcRow(s)** ("calculation" row(s)).

1. Including or omitting [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) is what determines if the results will be contiguous.
2. [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) passes each row, one by one, into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function that assigns the variable `r` to the current row.
3. The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula applies the [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=en) function to the values of three cells:

   - Current row:  `r`
   - One down:   `OFFSET(r,1,0)`
   - Two down:   `OFFSET(r,2,0)`
4. The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula is designed to trigger an error if `r` is not in a **calcRow** and/or if `r` is an empty cell.  [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) returns nothing in those cases.
5. The first test  `1/(1/NOT(MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3)))` returns `1` if `r` is in a **calcRow** or a `#DIV/0!` error if not.  A few functions and Sheets behaviors are leveraged to trigger these errors:

   1. First, the [MOD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497?hl=en) function is used to determine if the current row number `ROW(r)` (after first subtracting the row number containing the formula) is a multiple of `3`, ergo a **calcRow**:

      - **calcRow**: `MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3)=0`
      - ****nonCalcRow****: `MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3)<>0`
   2. The result from the last step is converted to `TRUE` for **calcRow** and `FALSE` for ****nonCalcRow**** by wrapping it in the [NOT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en) function:

      - **calcRow**: `NOT(MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3))=TRUE`
      - **nonCalcRow**: `NOT(MOD(ROW(r)-ROW(),3))=FALSE`
   3. The third and last step includes the calculation `1/(1/n)` (divide one by the inverse of a number).  This calculation always returns `n` where `n<>0` or `#DIV/0!` where `n=0`.  Since Sheets will coerce `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0` in math calculations, the TRUE/FALSE values from the previous steps can be combined with the calculation.  If it returns `1` that can be multiplied by the rest of the formula without impact:

      - **calcRow**: `1\(1\TRUE)=1`
      - **nonCalcRow**: `1\(1\FALSE)=#DIV/0!`
6. The second test checks that `r` contains a value and triggers an error if the cell is empty thereby limiting the original infinite range `A2:A` to only those `calc_rows` that contain a value.  This is done using the [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) function.

   - `LEN(r)` will return the total characters in the current row.
   - Again `1/(1/n)` is used again to trigger an error if `LEN(r)=0`
   - If `1/(1/LEN(r))` returns a number, it must be handled in some way as the number itself is of no use to the formula.  Since dividing a number by itself returns  `1` this is a way to convert the number to something that can be multiplied by the rest of the formula without impact.   Where `n<>0`:

     - `n/n = 1/(1/n)/n = 1`
7. So the [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula can essentially be simplified to the following use cases where only the first will return a value, the rest will error out and nothing will be returned:

   1. if a **calcRow** and `LEN(r)<>0`
      `IFERROR(1*1*AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0)))`
   2. if a **calcRow** and `LEN(r)=0` (empty)
      `IFERROR(1*#DIV/0!*AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0)))`
   3. if a **nonCalcRow** and `LEN(r)<>0`
      `IFERROR(#DIV/0!*1*AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0)))`
   4. if a **nonCalcRow** and `LEN(r)=0`
      `IFERROR(#DIV/0!*#DIV/0!*AVERAGE(r,OFFSET(r,1,0),OFFSET(r,2,0))`

Comment: Formula modified to allow zero values in the first row.

Answer (score -1):

See [Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brmySn1LyoFJ_m27VwKmcwEXIAfyGkbOXF-EhoU6bu4/edit#gid=0)

Formula in cell D2 returns average value for each 3 cells in column C (however in cell D1 you can specify number or if you need header remove it and change reference in formula to value)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
VLOOKUP(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(C2:C)/D1),1,1,1),
 {ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",REPT(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(C2:C)/D1),1,1,1)&",",D1)),","))),
 ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(
  ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",REPT(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(C2:C)/D1),1,1,1)&",",D1)),","))),
  ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",REPT(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(C2:C)/D1),1,1,1)&",",D1)),","))),
C2:C)/D1)},2,0))
```

Idea is to generate labels for data based on required number, e.g.

```
    A    Label
1   32   1 
2   25   1
3   10   1
4   14   2
5   87   2
6   32   2
7   5    3
8   97   3
9   73   3
```

Following formula generates those labels

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",REPT(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(C2:C)/D1),1,1,1)&",",D1)),",")))
```

Using SUMIF (unfortunately AVERAGEIF doesn't work with arrays) we get sum of 3 cells based on previos labels, then we divide it by value in cell D1 (in our case it's 3) and get average.

```
 A      Label Average
1   32   1    22
2   25   1    22
3   10   1    22
4   14   2    44
5   87   2    44
6   32   2    44
7   5    3    58
8   97   3    58
9   73   3    58
```

Since we don't need repeated 3 times average values, we use VLOOKUP to get average values for all labels.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and decided on a solution without a formula and thought I'd share. It's not very elegant but here it is:

Take the average of 3 cells and extend the formula, then we can filter for every 3rd.

create a column of `1,2,3,4....n`

A second column `modulo(1,2,3,4....n, 3)`

filter the second column for `values = 1`

Example:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1.01 |
| B | 2.02 |
| C | 3.03 |
| D | 1.11 |
| E | 2.22 |
| F | 3.33 |

Calculate the mean of ABC in the first column and then drag the formula...

Add two new columns n (=1,2,3...length of data) & modulo (= mod(n), 3), then filter modulo == 1

| ID | value | Mean | n | modulo ( = mod(n,3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.01 | =Mean(A,B,C) | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2.02 | =Mean(B,C,D) | 2 | 2 |
| C | 3.03 | =Mean(C,D,E) | 3 | 0 |
| D | 1.11 | =Mean(D,E,F) | 4 | 1 |
| E | 2.22 | =Mean(E,F,G) | 5 | 2 |
| F | 3.33 | =Mean(F,G,H) | 6 | 0 |

which will leave you the mean of ABC, DEF

Obviously not as elegant as using a formula but does seem a quick fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).